# Error en C++ taking adress of temporary [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, poo

Tengo un vector de objetos de la clase Materias, en esta funcion recibo una referencia al objeto unaMateria para eliminarla del mismo. en la linea donde, dentro del for hago (*it).getNombre() == &unaMateria.getNombre() sale el error del titulo, de que manera puedo hacer esa comparacion solucionando el error?

```
bool Carrera::eliminarMateria (Materia& unaMateria)
{
    if (this->materias.empty())
    {
        return false;
    }else
    {
        for (std::vector<Materia>::iterator it = this->materias.begin() ; it != this->materias.end(); ++it)
        {
            if ((*it).getNombre() == &unaMateria.getNombre())
            {
                this->materias.erase(&unaMateria);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando mal la función [`erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase), además de hacer una comparación incorrecta. Suponiendo que `getNombre` devuelve un `string`, el `&` está demás.

Si `getNombre` devuelve un `char*`, recuerda que la comparación fallará a menos que apunten a la misma dirección de memoria.

Recuerda que `erase` modifica la lista y devuelve un iterador nuevo que deberías utilizar. Aunque en este caso no es necesario ya que inmediatamente sales de la función.

```
for (auto it = this->materias.begin() ; it != this->materias.end(); )
{
    if (it->getNombre() == unaMateria.getNombre())
    {
        it = this->materias.erase(it);
        return true;
    }
    else
        ++it;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu error se puede replicar con [este sencillo código](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E3OScxL//@/uKSoNLlEIZirmoszM69EIU1DU6FaoSi1pLQoT8HAWqGWq9aaiwskk5uYmaehCVIXrFBsDVGtVaBgq6BWrAfUBVTFCdfGVfv/PwA):

```
struct S
{
    int f() { return 0; }
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    int *p = &s.f();

    return 0;
}
```

Como puedes ver la función `S::f` devuelve un entero (`int`) **por copia**, lo que sucede en esa función es que el literal `0` de la instrucción `return 0;` se copia en un entero **temporal** que es el que será devuelto por la función. Y no puedes obtener la dirección de un valor temporal porque este desaparece al finalizar la instrucción, de ahí el error.

Pero si fuese necesario, [puedes alargar la vida de un temporal](https://tio.run/##VYxBCoAgFAXX/lO8VVRQtJdO0QlELIL6if5W4dlNN0HbmWGs94M9DG85Rwm3FSz0kNpZsLYdHgQnd2BMGomSJqrmNDu3Xe0WRE3KXhwF1TTiTn8Fc2BGHMvhZ3tf8JeUmfrulHJ@AQ) devuelto por una función guardándolo en una referencia constante:

```
struct S
{
    int f() { return 0; }
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    const int &temporal = s.f();
    // Esto no provoca error
    const int *p = &temporal;

    return 0;
}
```

Pero en tu caso no es lo que quieres ya que la dirección de un temporal siempre será diferente, no puedes basar ninguna comparación en esa dirección de memoria. Probablemente querías comparar las cadenas no sus direcciones:

```
if ((*it).getNombre() == unaMateria.getNombre())
//                       ^ <--- Sin el 'et'.
{
    this->materias.erase(&unaMateria);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Es difícil poder ayudar sin tener más código para reproducir el problema. Sin embargo, esto podría funcionar (cambiar `this->materias.erase(&unaMateria)` por `this->materias.erase(it)`):

```
bool Carrera::eliminarMateria (Materia& unaMateria)
{
    if (this->materias.empty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (std::vector<Materia>::iterator it = this->materias.begin() ; it != this->materias.end(); ++it)
        {
            if ((*it).getNombre() == &unaMateria.getNombre())
            {
                this->materias.erase(it);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```